# Async vs Sync programming - Is it considered a style or does it offer more powerful programming options?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

Asynchronous programming has becoming much more popular, especially in the area of web development. The initial point given is always along the lines of "It prevents the UI from freezing etc etc". However, to my understanding the function that is called on the asynchronous callback will run on my main thread, within the exact same amount of time it would have executed before, meaning if the blocking function was called asynchronously vs synchronously, the UI would be the same. Take for example,

**Synchronous**

```
console.log("I will print")
function wait(ms) {
  var start = Date.now(),
      now = start;
  while (now - start < ms) {
    now = Date.now();
  }
}

wait(5000); 
console.log("I will not print, until after 5 seconds, due to synchronous execution")
```

**Asynchronous**

```
console.log("I will print")
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("I will print after the callback has been called asynchronously (~3000ms)")
    wait(5000); 
    console.log("I will print after 5 seconds")
}, 3000)
console.log("I will also print immediately")
```

The idea that I am trying to show here is that both Asynchronous and Synchronous calls both result in Frozen/Blocked UI if the method is heavy and slow, Asynchronous calls do not fix that. However, whenever I read online it is the main point trying to be shown.

So my question is, why is Asynchronous programming been considered highly recently, it is simply as preferred programming **style**? Does it offered some special abilities that Synchronous programming might struggle with?

Comment: If you have an event listener that listens to events while the asynchronous code is waiting, that event listener will still be able to process events because it does not block the event loop. The synchronous version will block the event loop.

Comment: `setTimeout` runs in the main thread, but the `XMLHttpRequest` does not.

Comment: I would also like to state that your `wait` function is just holding the document up from loading, since it's synchronous. `setTimeout` does not hold up the document. Since Browsers timeout, it's a bad practice to run any loops based on time. If you want to do loops based on time `setInterval`. It this case it looks like you just want `setTimeout`, though.

Comment: `why is Asynchronous programming been considered highly recently` by *recently*, do you mean since setTimeout/setInterval and asynchronous requests using XMLHttpRequest existed? because they've existed for a long time

Comment: Just ask, could Google Maps have happened without async?

Comment: @55Cancri If the event that it is processing is large, it will block the event loop, just like my example above. What exactly do you mean when you say it won't but the synchronous version will? The callback from the event is still ran on the main UI, meaning it can block the event loop and freeze the UI.

Comment: @user12388651 synchronous code will block the loop wherever it is placed. But even in the scenario you described, notice that the event loop is blocked by the event listener, not the async wait function. Now use that same blocking event listener for the synchronous wait. The event loop will be blocked by the wait function, not the event listener, because the event listener won't ever have a chance to run. The solution of course is to minimize the amount of synchronous, computationally-intensive code you have anywhere, or offset as much of it to async processing as possible.

Comment: @user12388651 JavaScript is great with async code but bad for computationally-intensive, synchronous operations because of the single-threaded nature of the event loop. Multi-threaded languages like C++ allow you to distribute that synchronous workload across multiple threads for faster performance. Node.js can somewhat achieve parallel processing with web workers.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, you have a sleep function that is synchronous and blocking. So whenever your function is called, it will block the event loop and halt the execution of future code. If you call it immediately like in your first example, the loop will be blocked instantly and the UI will freeze. If you wrap it in a `setTimeout` like in your second example, you merely delay the problem. Both of your examples demonstrate synchronous code.

The `setTimeout` will wait to execute any code it contains, such as your synchronous sleep function, until the end of the current event loop cycle. So the `console.log` statements and any other code you have after it will run first, then `setTimeout` will run at the end of the loop, and then the UI will be blocked. In order to demonstrate a proper comparison to asynchronous code, let's define a synchronous version of your sleep function and an asynchronous version:

```js
// synchronous sleep function that blocks the event loop
const SyncSleep = (ms) => {
    const start = Date.now(),
    let now = start;
    while (now - start < ms) {
        now = Date.now();
    }
    console.log('Sync timer ended.')
}

// async sleep function that does not block event loop
const asyncSleep = (ms) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    .then(() => console.log("Async timer finished."))
```

If we run the synchronous timer, we will see the following output:

```js
syncSleep(1000)
console.log('First.')
syncSleep(1000)
console.log('Second.')
syncSleep(1000)
console.log('Third.')

// Output:
// Sync timer ended.
// First.
// Sync timer ended.
// Second.
// Sync timer ended.
// Third​​.
```

Notice that any time `syncSleep` is called, it must completely wait for 1000ms, log `"Sync timer ended."`, and then finally move to the next line to log `"First."`. When it gets to the final `"Third"` log, it will have just spent 3 seconds and some change on the same event loop, highly wasteful, highly undesired. Compare this to the following:

```js
asyncSleep(1000)
console.log('First.')
asyncSleep(1000)
console.log('Second.')
asyncSleep(1000)
console.log('Third.')

// Output:
// First.
// Second.
// Third.​​
// Async timer ended.
// Async timer ended.
// Async timer ended.
```

The main thread is not blocked in this case, so all code defined on the event loop is run without delay. Here are the order of events:

It gets to the first `asyncSleep`, sees its a promise that doesn't resolve until later, so it throws it on the Callback Queue, and moves on to the next line. It then logs `"First."`, the first log you see in the output because the previous timer has not finished yet, and thus not logged anything. The event loop gets to the next `asyncSleep`, sees its a promise, so throws that one on the Callback Queue too, then moves to the next line. Next line outputs `"Second."`

Then the next line throws the final timer on the Callback Queue. Finally, the last line outputs `"Third."`. That entire event loop cycle finished in milliseconds, compared to the last example where the loop had to wait for everything to finish before completing even a single cycle around the event loop.

Now, a few more event loop cycles later, the first timer on the Callback Queue finishes after 1 second, so the promise resolves, the event loop pulls it down, and the timer's log statement is executed: `"Timer finished."`. The next journey around the event loop does the same thing, checks the Callback Queue, sees that the next timer is finished and outputs: `Timer finished.` again.

Does this all make sense now? In the first example with the synchronous timer, the code of the future timers and `console.log` statements was not able to run until all the previous timers finished. In your case, the UI was blocked. In the second case, the timer was handled asynchronously in the Callback Queue, and the event loop was able to traverse itself freely. As a result, all of the timers were able to be handled without having to wait for each other. In the end, the synchronous code took 3 seconds to run and the asynchronous code took 1 second. Change each of those timers to 3 seconds and the first sync program ends up taking 9 seconds and the second async program takes just 3 seconds, an exponential difference in time.

Of course, you could then await the async timers and then both programs end up to taking 3 seconds in the original example. However, the async version remains superior because its timers are handled in the Callback Queue, not in the event loop. So while the flow of both programs still proceeds in the manner of "wait 1 second, log `Timer ended.`, then log `First.`", the async version will be able to do other things while it is waiting on the timers to finish. In my comments above, those other things could be handling events in a separate event listener. In your case, it is handling the events of the UI. So if you have an event listener on a button that logs "button clicked" every time it is clicked, and you are waiting for those timers to finish in the Callback Queue, the button will still log those statements and the page will be totally responsive. Not so in the first example with the `SyncTimer`. Hope this was helpful.